# How to input a hex value in the Windows registry as DWORD?

Tags: c#, registry, dword

I would like to change a registry key with hex value of ffffffff , which is DWORD kind. I have a function:

```
public static void EditRegistryKey(string fullKeyName, string subKeyName, 
                                   string keyName, string keyValue, RegistryValueKind keyKind)
            {
                if (Registry.GetValue(fullKeyName, keyName, null) != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        RegistryKey myKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(subKeyName, true);
                        if (myKey != null)
                        {
                            myKey.SetValue(keyName, keyValue, keyKind);
                            myKey.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Trace.TraceInformation(ex.Message);
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
```

and when I try:

```
EditRegistryKey(  @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Config",
                @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Config",
                "MaxPosPhaseCorrection",
                "ffffffff",
                RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

I get an error that converson did not succed.

Comment: Well you sent a string... and then claimed it was something other than a string.  The .NET type which is equivalent to DWORD is `UInt32` (in C#, `uint`)

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to learn and doing stupid mistakes ...

Answer (score 0):

So, based on @Ben Voight comment I did this: changed a type of `keyValue` parameter to `object`and converted `ffffffff` to `Int32`. My function now takes a number or a string.

```
    public static void EditRegistryKey(string fullKeyName, string subKeyName, 
                                       string keyName, object keyValue, RegistryValueKind keyKind)
                {
                    if (Registry.GetValue(fullKeyName, keyName, null) != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            RegistryKey myKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(subKeyName, true);
                            if (myKey != null)
                            {
                                myKey.SetValue(keyName, keyValue, keyKind);
                                myKey.Close();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Trace.TraceInformation(ex.Message);
                            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
                }




 EditRegistryKey(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Config",
                        @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Config",
                        "MaxPosPhaseCorrection",
                        Convert.ToInt32("ffffffff", 16),
                        RegistryValueKind.DWord);

                        //Set syncronization to NTP server
    EditRegistryKey(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Parameters",
                    @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Parameters",
                    "Type",
                    "NTP",
                    RegistryValueKind.String);
```